# what does this shell script line of code means

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I found following few lines of code in .bashrc in my linux instance. could sombody explain me what does this line of codes means. i have no background in shell programming.

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

thanks in advance for any help

Comment: If that code is in your ~/.bashrc, remove it: bash is already reading your bashrc file. If it's in your ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile, leave it, it's fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[ -f ~/.bashrc]` [tests](http://linux.die.net/man/1/test) wheather a file `.bashrc` exists in the current home directory. If it exists, then it's sourced.

That means it is executed in the current shell, not by starting a new shell. So all changes in the script affect the current shell directly without having to export variables.

Comment: . ~/.bashrc are you sure this will run the bashrc file? ~/.bashrc will do his work.

Comment: simply executing `~/.bashrc` executes the file in a new shell, changes you make to the environment variable won't affect the old shell. `. ./.bashrc` executs the script in the current shell and is used to set up the environment. if you want to try it, put `echo something` in your .bashrc and start a new shell.

Comment: You mean inserting an echo into bashrc? It's just so you see that the script gets executed when you start a new bash session.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is the `if` condition statement in shell script programming language.
`if [-f ~/.bashrc]` means that if it is true that there is a file named `.bashrc` in your home directory, then when you login your linux system the `./bashrc` file will be run automatic by the init process. It is used to configure the system environment for you automatic.